# Haskell: lift a normal function to a lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have a HashMap that contains various things (Value is from Aeson):

```
cs :: Hashmap Text Value
cs = fromList [("phone", String "+00"), ("count", Number 1)]
```

I figured out I could extract elements easily with Lenses and in particular [lens-aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson-1.1):

```
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import Data.Lens

phone :: Maybe Text
phone = preview (at "phone" . _Just . _String) cs
```

This works well.
But How can I retrieve my count as a Int?
I tried:

```
count :: Maybe Int
count = preview (at "count" . _Just . _Number) cs
```

But this returns a `Maybe Scientific`.
I found (in Data-Scientific):

```
toBoundedInteger :: forall i. (Integral i, Bounded i) => Scientific -> Maybe i
```

How to lift `toBoundedInteger` to work as a Lens (or Prism) in my "preview" above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`folding`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:folding):

```
count :: Maybe Int
count = preview (at "count" . _Just . _Number . folding boundedInteger) cs
```

There is also [`to`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v:to) but it gives you an extra layer of `Maybe` that you have to collapse with `join`:

```
count :: Maybe Int
count = preview (at "count" . _Just . _Number . to boundedInteger . to join) cs
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the good answer. I tried previously: `preview (at "count" . _Just . _Number . _Just . to boundedInteger) cs` Why is it not working?

Comment: After `_Number` the target has type `Scientific`, not `Maybe a`. `_Just` is an optic with source type `Maybe a` (`Fold (Maybe a) a`), while `to boundedInteger` is an optic with source type `Scientific` (`Fold Scientific Int`).